# Mak all even/odd divs inside body only 1 level deep

Tags: html, css

Consider the html below

```
<body>
    <!-- mark div below level 1  -->
    <div class="container"> 
        <!-- dont mark div below level 2 -->
        <div class="some-class">

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- mark div below level 1  -->
    <div class="container"> 
        <!-- dont mark div below level 2 -->
        <div class="some-class">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

now using the DRY principle is there a way to mark every other div inside body and stop at level 1?

```
body div:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
body div:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

the above will also mark some-class i need it to stop at level one, can this be obtained with css, or de i have to use javascript?
Keep in mind i only want to use the DRY principle
so giving them all an extra class aint a posibility

Comment: Give the first container an extra class and use that?

Comment: You probably want to replace “layer” with “level” in your question title and body.

Comment: Innervisions, thanks for your input, but thats working against the DRY principles.

Noted Jcaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have two possibilities:

```
body > div:nth-child(…) { … }
```

This will only select the direct children of body. Or

```
body div:nth-child(…) { … }
body div:nth-child(…) div { /* undo marking */ }
```

If possible, the first one is obviously preferable.

Comment: Alright, i've tested it out now, and it works like a charm, thanks for the help SourceOverflow